# Externalization of postgreSQL database from windows comtainer

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers, windows-container, windows-server-container

I have an APP running inside container on windows 2016 platform . The app uses the postgreSQL database .we want to persist the database when container destroy and another container up  again . So we want to persist the database record . I see the postgress container for Linux platform but not for windows container .We are using window server core image as base . Can someone suggest how can we persist database info.

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

The program will run in the Windows container. The DB will run in a Linux container. Since they're in different containers, the OS needn't be the same. You'll simply be connecting to the DB over a URL in a network.

Comment: Thanks for response . Customer is using windows platform and running Linux container on windows platform is  still in development . Even running on hyperv is not option as it creates problem in accessing file system

Comment: Can you use https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express/ or https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer/ ?